# What article must one use, when the object is specified parenthetically?

Tags: articles

Which variant is correct in a sentense like "Old books may be impressive: I like a/the book (*Hamlet*) written a few centuries ago"?

On the one hand, the object is specific and I would expect the definite article there. But, on the other hand, it is somewhat strange that the choice of article would depend on some optional information.

Comment: Try "I **would** like *a* book ..." with the indefinite article or "I like book**s** ..." with the zero article.

Comment: The choice of article does not depend on optional information. No native speaker would ever write *the* there. Use *a*. You like *a* book written a few centuries ago. Even the order does not matter. If you write, "I like *Hamlet*, a book written a few centuries ago", you'll still use *a*. You would never use *the* there. There's more than one book that was written a few centuries ago. That fact does not change just because you name one book. There are still many, many other books. You are talking about *a* book.

Comment: Are you saying that the choice depends on the pesence of parentheses? "I like a  book (Hamlet) written ,,,", but "I like the  book Hamlet written ,,,"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The choice of article does *not* depend on optional information.

You would write either

> Old books can be impressive. I like a book written  a few centuries ago.

or

> Old books can be impressive. I like a book (*Hamlet*)  written  a few centuries ago.

Providing the book's name in parentheses does not change the article.  The same is true if you set the title of the book off with two commas.

> Old books can be impressive. I like a book, *Hamlet*,   written  a few centuries ago.

However   if you do not set the book's name off by parentheses or two commas, you would use *the*

> Old books can be impressive. I like the book *Hamlet*,  written  a few centuries ago.

You use *the* because you are naming the book in the independent clause; you are not just providing the name as additional information, in parentheses or set off by commas, almost as a favor to the reader.

Notice that in this last sentence, the reduced relative clause *(which was) written a few centuries ago* is a non-restrictive relative clause. A non-restrictive relative clause itself provides optional information and can be deleted without changing the rest of the sentence.

Thus you can write

> Old books can be impressive. I   like the book *Hamlet*.

On the other hand, I can't think of a context in which

> ? Old books can be impressive. I  like a book *Hamlet*

would be grammatical.

You could say

> Old books can be impressive. I like a book called *Hamlet*.

Here you use *a* (make an indefinite reference) because your listener probably doesn't know which book you mean.

> Old books can be impressive. I like the book called *Hamlet*.

Here you make a definite reference, perhaps because you wish to make 'the book called *Hamlet*' the topic of discussion.

In both these last two examples, you can also add the non-restrictive relative clause.

Comment: Thank you for such a detailed answer (unfurtunately, I cannot vote)

Comment: @Serguei No problem. Glad it was useful.

Answer (score 0):

The choice of "a" or "the" depends on whether you have a specific thing in mind or want your listener to be thinking specifically or generally.

> I like Japanese films. Have you seen *the* Kurosawa film, *Dersu
>   Uzala*?

Visiting the DVD section of a brick-and-mortar store, asking the salesperson:

> I'm looking for *a* Japanese film. Do you happen to have the film *Dersu Uzala*
>   on DVD?

At first, you're just orienting the salesperson to the genre. You don't have a specific title at that point.

To use you example:

**I like the play *Hamlet*, which was written over four centuries ago.**

or

**There's a play I especially like -- *Hamlet* -- you may have heard of it. It was written over four centuries ago.**

Comment: And what article would it be in my example (it seems to me quite different from yours)?

Comment: Old plays can be good.  I like the play *Hamlet*. I forget who wrote it.

Comment: The comma is wrong. Last I checked, Kurosawa had made more than one film.

Comment: Comma shmomma.  Mere convention.  We're talking grammar not schoolmarmery.

Comment: Sorry for nitpicking, but could you confirm that in MY example it must be "a": "I like a book (Hamlet) written ,,,"

Comment: I don't think you're following my answer, because nowhere am I saying that it must be "a".  It *can* be *a* or it can be *the*. It depends on what you're trying to say.  I have no idea what you're trying to say by putting the name Hamlet inside parentheses.

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to say by putting a name (Hamlet) inside parentheses.

Comment: *This is a picture of a man (Rasputin)* makes little sense.

Comment: Hm... I hoped the example was transparent. Will it be clearer if I reword it as "I like a/the book (_Hamlet_, specifically) written..." , or "I like a/the book (acually, it is _Hamlet_) written..."

Comment: Saying it in that way is analogous to the last example in the answer I gave, *There's a play I like...*. This is a conversational strategy where you *introduce* your listener to something and you don't necessarily assume that they know it specifically by name. Hence "a" instead of "the". But your actual sentence is at odds with the strategy because *Hamlet* is one of the most famous plays, if not the most famous play, on the planet. So it is like saying "There's *a* liquid I drink when I'm thirsty -- it's called water. Have you had it?"

Comment: It seems I'm failing to invent an adequate example. Let me try once more. It was intended to sound rather like "I drink a liquid when I'm thirsty (as a matter of fact this liquid is water, but this is not important at the moment), so I can't fly  this flight (because all liquids are prohibitted there whatsoever)"

Comment: You must give a real sentence whose context is clear. The choice of article is a nuanced thing and context-dependent. Idiomatic: "I eat at a little bistro (it's called *Harry's*, by the way) and you'll never guess who came in the door today!". Also idiomatic: "I eat at the little bistro down by the river (it's called *Harry's*, BTW) and you'll never guess who came in the door today!"   The first assumes the listener is unfamiliar with the place. The second suggests the speaker thinks the listener has heard about the bistro, but does not know its name and has not been there personally.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37668/discussion-between-serguei-and-tromano).